# Why sort() using Math.random() is different from using a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, random, shuffle

I have two different results using the same range of numbers. Sorry if it is obvius, I am a total beginner and couldn't find the answer for this.

This below shuffles the array.

```js
(function(array) {
    array.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
    console.log(array);
})([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
// Output: [Shuffled array]
```

However, if I manually write a random number between -0.5 and 0.5, I can't shuffle it. Why??

```js
(function(array) {
    array.sort(() => 0.2145467);
    console.log(array);
})([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
// Output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I am confused. Three answers from 15k+ community members and 3 downvotes and zero comments for the newcomer. Looks like the community is polarized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sort` callback takes *two* items from the array (which you ignore entirely) and is supposed to return a number < 0, == 0, or > 0 to indicate which of the two items is greater or whether they're equal. **The callback is called many times,** once for each random pair of items the algorithm needs to compare. If you return an actual random number, then each pair of items is determined to be greater/equal/less based on a custom number every time. If you hardcode a number, then the result is the same for all items.

See:

```js
(function(array) {
    array.sort((a, b) => {
      const r = 0.5 - Math.random();
      console.log(a, b, r);
      return r;
    });
    console.log(array);
})([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the callback function can be one of three things:

- Less than 0 (meaning one is less than the other)
- 0 (meaning the values are the same)
- Greater than 0 (meaning they are the other way around)

If you return a fixed number then the sort order will be constant.

If you return a `0.5 -` a random number between 0 and 1 then it would be any on of the three.

Comment: @Christian — `Math.random()` generates a **different** random number each time it is called so you *can't* replace it with "the random one" because there are **many** random ones.

Comment: I got it know. Now everything makes sense! Thanks, Quentin. Sorry if the question looked stupid, I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

In the 1st snippet, the inline function `() => 0.5 - Math.random()` is evaluated **multiple times**, each time producing a different value (sometimes < 0 and sometimes > 0, or perhaps even === 0), resulting in a random sort order.

In the 2nd snippet, the inline function `() => 0.2145467` is *also* evaluated **multiple times**, however each time it produces the same value (always > 0), resulting in a fixed sort order.